# How can I can all unique user whom I send message and receive message

Tags: mysql, sql, jpa, jpql

I have table in which all conversation is stored like this

Suppose I have a table like this (fromUser and toUser is fk from user table)

```
-----------------------------------------
Id.  |  FromUser  |  toUser  | message  |  
     |            |          |          |
1    |     1      |    2     |  Hi      |
2    |     2      |    1     |  hello   |  
3    |     3      |    1     |  hi      |
4    |     1      |    4     |  hello   |
-----------------------------------------
```

Desired output for distinct row for user 1  orderBy last updated date

```
-----------------------------------------
Id.  |  FromUser  |  toUser  | message  |  
     |            |          |          |
2    |     2      |    1     |  hello   |  
3    |     3      |    1     |  hi      |
4    |     1      |    4     |  hello   |
-----------------------------------------
```

Desired output for distinct row for user 2 orderBy last date

```
-----------------------------------------
Id.  |  FromUser  |  toUser  | message  |  
     |            |          |          |
2    |     2      |    1     |  hello   |  
-----------------------------------------
```

Desired output for distinct row for user 3 orderBy last date

```
-----------------------------------------
Id.  |  FromUser  |  toUser  | message  |  
     |            |          |          |
3    |     3      |    1     |  hi      |
-----------------------------------------
```

As well for other users

Comment: Where is your `last date` field in schema?

Comment: let assume table is in order by updated date.. last entry added having updated time and I want to consider last entry as row

Comment: Let's assume you are somewhere using the JPA API, then you would know that CLASSES are of importance not TABLES, so post the classes instead of the tables. If instead you are simply wanting SQL then remove the JPA tag

Answer (score 0):

The query I came up with is a bit complex, so here it is in multiple steps:

1) Get the “Other User” for the message matching the requested user.

```
SET @id = 1;
SELECT id, FromUser, ToUser, updateDate,
       IF(FromUser=@id, ToUser, FromUser) as OtherUser
  FROM user_msgs 
  WHERE @id=FromUser OR @id=ToUser;
```

2) Wrap the above and get the last updateDate. (see below for user 'id' instead)

```
SET @id = 1;
SELECT OtherUser, max(updateDate) as updateDate FROM
   (
    SELECT id, FromUser, ToUser, updateDate,
          IF(FromUser=@id, ToUser, FromUser) as OtherUser
     FROM user_msgs 
     WHERE @id=FromUser OR @id=ToUser
   ) AS i1
 GROUP BY OtherUser;
```

3) **FULL QUERY HERE** ... Finally wrap again to get the desired records.

```
SET @id = 1;
```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM user_msgs O
>   WHERE EXISTS
>   (
>     SELECT * FROM 
>      (
> ```
>
> > ```
> >      SELECT OtherUser, min(updateDate) as updateDate FROM
> >        (
> > ```
> >
> > > ```
> > >          SELECT id, FromUser, ToUser, updateDate,
> > >               IF(FromUser=@id, ToUser, FromUser) as OtherUser
> > >            FROM user_msgs 
> > >            WHERE @id=FromUser OR @id=ToUser
> > > ```
> >
> > ```
> >         ) AS i1
> >        GROUP BY OtherUser
> > ```
>
> ```
>      ) i2
>    WHERE O.updateDate = i2.updateDate AND
>            (( O.FromUser=@id AND i2.OtherUser = O.ToUser) OR
>             ( O.ToUser=@id AND i2.OtherUser = O.FromUser) )
>   );
> ```

*Note: If you don’t have a last date "updateDate" field, and instead are using “id” (I wasn’t sure), then just replace all the “updateDate” field occurrences in the query with “id”.*

SQL Fiddle: [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dbbdaf/6)

Comment: Thanks for replying but It's too complex to even understand. Do you have better query or JPA query?

Comment: Sorry, dude. I would also be interested as a point of learning if someone else could simplify the pure SQL further. I guess it would be simpler to read the code if you just SQL `SELECT WHERE @id=FromUser OR @id=ToUser` and use procedural code to filter out the duplicate records.